# Word meaning "quality of belonging to a library"?

Tags: single-word-requests

> I couldn't find anything about Web 2.0 at the library. Seems like
>   the topic isn't very [...].

I thought about *academic,* but I think that that word is probably wrong because it is more applicable to a school or university.

Comment: The word 'library' itself, used attributively, is often enough. Thus 'library rules', or if you want a more '_belonging_ belonging' example,  'In the first week at my new school, I borrowed a library copy of The Count of Monte Cristo' [internet].

Comment: "... isn't very well understood" would be accurate.

Comment: "...isn't very **well-documented**"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would proffer **[depository library](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/depository%20library)**

- (n.)- a depository built to contain books and other materials for reading and study

Comment: How does this fit to the example sentence?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're looking for an adjective like [**scholarly:**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/scholarly)

> 1 Involving or relating to serious academic study:
>
> EXAMPLE SENTENCES
>
> *scholarly journals*
>
> *a scholarly career*
>
> *Few if any of the serious scholarly treatments of the Cold War and its end credit a single policy or factor or agent.*
>
> *There is no paucity of scholarly studies and statistical data on China, but these do not help us.*
>
> *His articles and case studies on these topics have appeared in numerous scholarly journals and books.*

(Definition and examples from Oxforddictionaries.com)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe "catalogued"?  "A copy of every book published in the US is *catalogued* in the Library of Congress."